# How to automatically generate a range of buttons with pre-determined onclick events?

Tags: onclick

I am trying to generate a button from a range X; in this case, from 0 to 25, and when I click in one generate button, it will alert the word eggs. I followed the rules to generate an on click event on an element through JavaScript, but the code didn't work. What is wrong with the code?
The code is in the link. Unfortunately, I couldn't upload it through CTRL+K stackoverflow feature.

https://textuploader.com/1gynb

Answer (score 0):

Hei,

Not a javascript expert but I think this does what you want:

```
<p id='ai'>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>

<button onclick="generator()">Try it</button>

<script>

  function generator() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
      var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      btn.innerHTML = x;
      btn.setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction();");
      document.getElementById('ai').innerHTML += btn.outerHTML;
    }
  }

  function myFunction() {
    console.log("done")
  }

</script>
```